# # in conditionals in alignment tabs?

Tags: tables, tex-core, conditionals

I am looking for ideas how to make TeX understand that when # appears both in the *if-else* and in the *else-fi* part of a conditional in an alignment tab, in the end there will never be more than one # in the tab.  Here is some sample code:

```
\def\table{
   \halign{
      \iftrue\hfil##\else##\hfil\fi\cr
      Bla-bla\cr}}
\table
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can pretend to have two `#` in the template by using a macro:

```
\newif\ifright
\def\table{%
  \halign{%
    \def\temp{##}\ifright\hfil\temp\else\temp\hfil\fi\cr
    Bla-bla\cr
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\cr
  }%
}

% \rightfalse
\table

\righttrue
\table

\bye
```

[image]

Alternatively, use `\span`

```
\newif\ifright
\def\table{%
  \halign{%
    \span\ifright\hfil##\span\else##\hfil\span\fi\cr
    Bla-bla\cr
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\cr
  }%
}

% \rightfalse
\table

\righttrue
\table

\bye
```

Comment: How about not using `\newif` and `\span`: `\halign{\def\hash{#}\iftrue\hfil\hash\else\hash\hfil\fi\cr Bla-bla\cr}`

Comment: Or maybe even better (no extra macros): `\halign{\span\iftrue\hfil#\span\else#\hfil\span\fi\cr Bla-bla\cr}`

Comment: @AngelTsankov Of course; but I thought you had a purpose in having `\halign` inside a macro.

Comment: Yes, I meant to have `\halign` inside a macro.  However, I cannot get the point of `\newif\ifright` and `\def\temp{##}` when just `\span` seems to suffice (both when `\halign` is in a macro and when it is not).

Answer (score 6):

Are you looking for something like the following

```
\let\hash\relax
\def\table#1{%
  \edef\preamble{\iftrue\hfil\hash\else\hash\fi\cr}%
  \let\hash##
  \expandafter\halign\expandafter{\preamble #1}%
  \let\hash\relax
}
\table{a\cr b\cr}
\bye
```

The idea here is that during the 'construction' phase we represent `#` using a non-expandable token; only during the actual table construction is `\hash` equal to `#`. In this way there is never a conditional containing multiple `#` tokens.

Comment: The LaTeX kernel's approach for creating the `tabular` environment uses a similar idea, with the name `\@sharp` for `#` (see `\@mkpream` and so on).

Comment: What is the purpose of `\let\hash\relax` at the beginning?

Comment: @AngelTsankov Try without and see :-) The `\edef` will expand everything it can, and if `\hash` is undefined you'll get an error.

Answer (score 6):

As an alternative to Joseph's you can hide the duplication in a macro (at the expense of passing each cell through a macro expansion)

```
\def\foo#1{\iftrue\hfil#1\else#1\hfil\fi}
\def\table{%
   \halign{\foo{##}\cr
      Bla-bla\cr}}
\table

\bye
```

Answer (score 2):

I'am using toks register `\tabdata` for such purposes where the `\halign` preamble is created  step by step. The advatage of this is that the macro `\table` can create arbitrary `\halign` preamble according to special language offered to user. The algorithm can scan such language and it can create `\halign` preamble using `\addtabdata` macro.

```
\newif\ifright
\newtoks\tabdata

\def\table{\tabdata={}% the \tabdata idea inspired from OPmac
   \ifright \addtabdata{\hfil##}\else\addtabdata{##\hfil}\fi
   \halign\expandafter{\the\tabdata\cr
      ddghsghdfs\cr fghdg\cr}
}
\def\addtabdata#1{\tabdata=\expandafter{\the\tabdata#1}}

\table

\righttrue
\table

\end
```